# Regex to match complementary subgroups of a folder's contents (webpack vendor bundles)

Tags: javascript, regex, npm, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to figure out two regex expressions that I'll use with Webpack to create two different vendor bundles.

Here's a simplified list of what my `node_modules` folder looks like:

- `autonumeric`
- `core-js`
- `jquery`
- `jquery-ui`
- `jquery.watch`
- `marked`

The first vendor bundle should be the "essentials" bundle, which, let's say, are `jquery` and `core-js`.

- `core-js`
- `jquery`

The second vendor bundle should contain all the other bundles in `node_modules`, *except* for `jquery` and `core-js` (That means the regex must match `jquery-ui`).

- `autonumeric`
- `jquery-ui`
- `jquery.watch`
- `marked`

Here are my current regex expressions:

- essentials bundle: `/node_modules\/(jquery|core-js)\/.*\.js/`
- "rest of" bundle: `/node_modules(?!\/(jquery|core-js))(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)+\.js`

The problem is that the second regex doesn't match the `jquery*` libraries, probably because of the negative lookahead starting with `jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check for the `/` char after `jquery` or `core-js` since you need to only fail them as whole subfolder name:

```
node_modules(?!\/(jquery|core-js)\/)(\/[^\/]+)+\.js
                                 ^^
```

Or, if there can also be end of string:

```
node_modules(?!\/(jquery|core-js)(\/|$))(\/[^\/]+)+\.js
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1Njld/1)

Note I also suggest replacing `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+` with a more generic `[^\/]+` that matches any 1+ chars other than `/`, but you may keep your pattern if your requirements are more specific.